# jDatabase request whith 2 times the same field under condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to request a table which looks like this:

Table1

| record | element | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 62 | 56 | 637689 |
| 62 | 163 | 12/1990 |

...
joined with another table:

Table2

| user_id | record |
| --- | --- |
| 64 | 62 |

expecting this result: 637689,"12/1990" based on user_id=64 (not implemented in my request as i am unable to write the correct JOIN syntax

i tried with this request:

```
 SELECT record,
   (CASE WHEN element = 163 THEN value END) AS numserie,
   (CASE WHEN element = 56 THEN value END) AS dateprod
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY record
   ORDER BY record DESC;
```

, but in heidiSQL, i have this result

| numserie | dateprod |
| --- | --- |
| 637689 | NULL |

i tried on others "element" number, always NULL

i tried to swap the two CASE lines, the result swap either

What is wrong ?

Comment: JOIN the tables on the shared `record` column, then use MAX() to merge the values into a single row  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7c6d639ac99e29a4f66ae83938c34cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate the `CASE` expressions.  Using the `MAX` function is one option:

```sql
SELECT
    record,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element = 163 THEN value END) AS numserie,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element = 56  THEN value END) AS dateprod
FROM Table1
GROUP BY record
ORDER BY record DESC;
```

Comment: Many thanks... it works !the query i had for example used the SUM function, so i deleted it
Now i have to find the right syntax to query with jDatabase (Joomla)